# Python: function defined in while loop refers to old variable

Tags: python, function, variable-binding

I have a function that I define in a while loop that is called by code I do not control.

In the following example, access() always returns the value 1. Why? And how can I make access() return the latest value?

```py
while True:
    g = [1,2,3]

    def access():
        return g[0]

    print(access())
    g[0] += 1
```

The same seems to be true for lambdas. I cannot make g global.

Comment: No need for function access to be in the while loop in this case (makes software overly confusing).

Comment: @DarrylG An external library possibly calls this function after I passed it to it

Comment: @2080 so what? It still shouldn't be defined in the loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How else could I make it refer to newly generated data inside the loop?

Comment: It will do that even if you define it outside the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `g` variable is always reinitialized to `[1,2,3]`.

Just move it outside the `while` *loop*.

```
g = [1,2,3]
while True:
    .....
```